# Are there any ready to use open source websocket server implementation?

Tags: open-source, socket

Are there some open source websocket server implementations, especially ready for production? (Are there Erlang based out there?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) on the client. And node.js with socket.io on the server. Works great. Mainly due to this. Socket.io will try websockets first.. If the browser doesn't support them fall back to flash sockets. If that doesn't work fall back to ajax style polling.